# iOS I am getting a warning about incomplete implementation for UITableViewDataSource

Tags: xcode, uitableview, warnings

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [(NSSet *)[team valueForKey:@"players"] count];
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: They are warning for you to not forget to return value from these function. you can delete them.

Comment: yes I know they are warnings @Scar . How can I correct them? I did return a value and it's still giving me warnings.

Comment: it seems that the last part of my comment is invisible to you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're returning values​​, just delete the lines:

```
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.

#warning Incomplete method implementation.
```

Comment: Just curious, I had the same issue and I have deleted the lines and they are still showing warnings on blank lines. What can I do?  I do return in each method